# Copy Jupyter notebook to a different location in the tree?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

How do I move a Jupyter notebook from /a/b to /c/d in the Jupyter tree?

When I select "Make a Copy..." in the notebook, it makes another copy in /a (i.e. /a/b-Copy).

Answer (score 0):

Someone told me an answer: open up a terminal in Jupyter and copy the notebook file from one place to another.